# htop reports high CPU% for process with low CPU% in visualization

Tags: top, cpu-usage, htop

I am trying to get a practical understanding of load in a server application. The application reads a large volume of data on a TCP connection. When I examined CPU utilization with `htop`, the process often reports high (85-100+%) CPU%, though the CPU visualization in `htop` amounts to much lower. The CPU% reported is similar in `top`.

Example output - processes with pid 26655/26656 of user tom have CPU% of 96.2, while we appear to only use 6.9% of CPU 1 and 37.4% of CPU 2, amounting to 44.3% total CPU utilization.

```
  1  [|||                       6.9%]   Tasks: 48, 128 thr; 2 running
  2  [||||||||||||||           37.4%]   Load average: 0.06 0.10 0.09
  Mem[|||||||||||||||||||1.10G/3.70G]   Uptime: 1 day, 15:16:55
  Swp[                         0K/0K]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
26655 tom        24   4 3216M 63832 13056 S 96.2  1.6  0:33.24 java -jar java_go
26656 tom        24   4 3216M 63832 13056 R 96.2  1.6  0:32.31 java -jar java_go
  986 jerry      20   0 3576M  594M 18268 S 18.3 15.7  4h13:46 java -Dcom.sun.ma
 1479 jerry      20   0 3576M  594M 18268 S 16.3 15.7  3h37:02 java -Dcom.sun.ma
26881 tom        20   0  129M  2392  1540 R  1.0  0.1  0:00.08 htop
```

Running the process with `time` reveals that user time plus system time is  far less than actual time, suggesting the visualization is more accurate:

```
real    1m26.787s
user    0m32.344s
sys     0m23.024s
```

(`user + sys / real = 0.6380`)

I then compared this `htop` behavior using a nonsense program that repeatedly performs exponentiation to consume CPU. The `htop` output is closer to what I expect - the process in question consumes 105% CPU, and the visualization suggests 100% of CPU 1 is used. Notice, however, 105% CPU consumption is reported, while total CPU% is only 102.2%.

```
  1  [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   Tasks: 46, 117 thr; 2 running
  2  [|||                       2.2%]   Load average: 0.39 0.11 0.08
  Mem[|||||||||||||||||||1.06G/3.70G]   Uptime: 1 day, 15:12:23
  Swp[                         0K/0K]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
25636 tom        20   0  122M  4604  2032 R 105.  0.1  0:16.32 /usr/bin/python .
  986 jerry      20   0 3576M  595M 18268 S 10.5 15.7  4h13:18 java -Dcom.sun.ma
 1479 jerry      20   0 3576M  595M 18268 R  9.1 15.7  3h36:35 java -Dcom.sun.ma
25714 tom        20   0  129M  2360  1540 R  1.4  0.1  0:00.04 htop
 1298 groot      20   0  173M 67784 11240 S  0.7  1.7  0:04.67 splunkd -p 8089 s
 1247 groot      20   0  173M 67784 11240 S  0.7  1.7  9:11.01 splunkd -p 8089 s
```

Why do the individual process lines in both `top` and `htop` report far higher utilization than the CPU visualization in `htop`?

I started my investigation earlier by looking at [this SO post on CPU utilization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15620/htop-does-not-show-the-correct-cpu-but-top-does), which seemed to reaffirm my prior understanding: CPU utilization is `<process_clock>/<wall_clock>`. I understand we can hide and reveal kernel and user entries in `htop`, but I would expect that would answer why the visualization has higher utilization than the sum of the process entries in the list below, not the other way around.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

- OS: CentOS 7
- Server: AWS t2.medium instance

I have additionally read up on stolen CPU in XEN hypervisors on AWS [here](https://axibase.com/news/ec2-monitoring-the-case-of-stolen-cpu/), suggesting using CloudWatch is a more effective way to get a practical understanding of resource usage for scaling reasons; however, I am still curious to know why `htop` would report excess CPU consumption for a given process, since this link suggests I should see I can't bring the sum of CPU% for my processes above a certain amount, not that I should see the discrepancy described in this post.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? htop uses different ways of collecting data on different platforms so that could matter. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Added information above (CentOS 7 on a t2.medium instance; please see remark about hypervisor CPU measurements). Thanks!